# How to prevent a click from passing through a fixed positioned element to the element behind it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed positioned header which has a searchbox in it and there is some content behind it (The header has higher z-index). I have an event handler which handles the 'focus' event on the searchbox. The problem is that when I click in the searchbox, this event handler triggers, but the click also passes through the header to the elements behind it. I don't want the click to pass through. I tried `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropagating()` and `event.cancelBubble = true` but none of them seems to work.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();`, **tion** instead of **ting**

Comment: Try setting `z-index: -1; position: relative` to your content element behind it (pushing the contents behind the `body`) OR try bringing the `body` above the your behind contents by setting a slightly higher `z-index` to your `body` than your behind contents.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, yeah I had used event.stopPropagation() only.

Comment: Nikhil, I tried setting position:relative and a lower z-index to the content, but it still does't work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to stop the propagation of the focus event.

Try binding the click event of the searchbox and use event.stopPropagation() on it.